# PHP reg_ex finding multiple words in a string

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

The nature of the situation, I need 1 pattern to do the following:

Create pattern that should find

1. exact match for single words
2. an exact match for a combination of 2 words.
3. a match of 2 words that could be found in a string.

My issue is with #3.  Currently I have:

```
$pattern = '/\s*(foo|bar|blah|some+text|more+texted)\s*/';
```

How can I append to this pattern that will find "bad text" in any combination in a string.

Any ideas?

Comment: It's pretty unclear what you're looking for here. Can you restate the question?

Answer (score 1):

To check string for word **bad** use regex

```
  /\bbad\b/
```

To check string for phrase **bad text** use regex

```
  /\bbad text\b/
```

To check string for any combination of words **bad** and **text** use regex

```
  /\b(bad|text)\s+(?!\1)(?:bad|text)\b/
```

To check string for presence of words **bad** and **text** use regex

```
  /(?=.*\bbad\b)(?=.*\btext\b)/
```

Comment: @user1724102 - Then please accept my answer by clicking check mark on left, next to my answer below number with arrows (will turn to green). Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Couple ways to do this, but here's an easy one

```
$array_needles = array("needle1", "needle2", etc...); 
$array_found_needles = array(); 

$haystack = "haystack";

foreach ($array as $key=>$val) {
    if(stristr($haystack, $val) {
    //do whatever you want if its found
    $array_found_needles[] = $val; //save the value found
    }
} 

$found = count($array_found_needles);

if ($found == 0) {
    //do something with no needles found
} else if($found == 1) {
    //do something with 1 needle found 
} else if($found == 2) {
    //do something with two needles found, etc
}
```